# entity framework programming against interface and repository pattern

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, repository-pattern

I am developing in ASP.NET MVC3 and EntityFramework.

I want my model to follow an interface :

```
public class Account : IAccount
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public string Language { get; set; }
}

public interface IAccount
{
    string Id { get; set; }

    DateTime Date { get; set; }

    string Language { get; set; }
}
```

Here's my Context

```
public class EFContext : DbContext, IContext
{
    public DbSet<Account> Accounts { get; set; }
}
```

And here's the repository :

```
public interface IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    IQueryable<T> All { get; }
    int Count { get; }

    bool Contains(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate);

    void Create(T item);

    void Update(T item);

    void Delete(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate);
    void Delete(T item);
}

public class EFRepository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    private EFContext _context;

    public EFRepository(IUnitOfWork uow)
    {
        this._context = (EFContext)uow.Context;
    }

    protected DbSet<T> DbSet
    {
        get
        {
            return _context.Set<T>();
        }
    }

    public IQueryable<T> All
    {
        get
        {
            return DbSet.AsQueryable();
        }
    }

    public virtual int Count
    {
        get
        {
            return DbSet.Count();
        }
    }

    public bool Contains(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
    {
        return DbSet.Count(predicate) > 0;
    }

    public virtual void Create(T item)
    {
        DbSet.Add(item);
    }

    public virtual void Update(T TObject)
    {
        var item = DbSet.Attach(TObject);

        _context.SetItemState(TObject, EntityState.Modified);
    }

    public virtual void Delete(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
    {
        var objects = DbSet.Where(predicate);

        foreach (var obj in objects)
        {
            DbSet.Remove(obj);
        }
    }

    public virtual void Delete(T TObject)
    {
        DbSet.Remove(TObject);
    }
}
```

Now, I want to use `IRepository<IAccount>` but this will ask the context for `DbSet<IAccount>`. This leads to an error since the Context contains a `DbSet<Account>`.

I then tried the solution proposed here for Linq2Sql : http://iridescence.no/post/Linq-to-Sql-Programming-Against-an-Interface-and-the-Repository-Pattern.aspx

So I added this function to my EFContext

```
public new DbSet<T> Set<T>() where T : class
{
    var ciccio = TableMaps[typeof(T)];
    return (DbSet<T>)base.Set(ciccio).Cast<T>();
}
```

But it doesn't work.

Do anyone have a suggestion?
Thx

Comment: "It doesn't work" is not an intelligent way to debug a problem. What is the error message?

Comment: @Slauma, an interface is not incompatible with `T` when a `where T : class` is present.

Comment: @smartcaveman: True, I even didn't know that until now. Deleted my comment which was obvious nonsense then. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

What benefit are you receiving from using an interface for your entities?  I don't see any value here.  Typically, you use Interfaces to remove dependencies upon the implementation, but that's not what you're achieving here because you're returning a concrete DbSet of objects.

Your entities are already Poco's.  They don't have dependencies on other implemntations, and they have no code in them other than a getter/setter.  Using an interface is redundant and pointless.

Comment: I am using interfaces because I need to switch between EF and Linq2Sql.

In this way the controllers use the interface and EF and Linq2Sql can implement their own classes for the model

Comment: @user1012750 - You can use a common Poco model for both, without interfaces.  For how to do poco in L2S see the answer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1407342/does-linq-to-sql-support-poco

Comment: @user1012750 - this is a textbook example of the XY problem. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem - Instead of asking how to share a common model between L2S and EF, you instead come up with a silly solution that you can't make work, and then ask how to make your silly solution work.

Comment: Well, first of all I didn't ask how to make my silly solution work... I just asked for suggestions. 

So, thanks for the suggestion, but I dont see how to share a common model between the two techs.

Comment: @user1012750 - Hey, no sweat off my back. I gave you a solution to your real problem and you choose to ignore it and get huffy.  Getting mad at people trying to help you does not do you any good, it just alienates those that try to help you.

Comment: Well, i am not getting mad at all. I thank you again for your answer. 
I didn't ask for fixing my solution, so your answer saying that my approach may not be good is absolutely fine. 
But again, I dont see how to share the model between L2S and EF.

BTW : I may have found a workaround. I am posting it... Any comments on it would be appreciated.

Comment: @user1012750 - I don't see where you have posted anything.

Comment: @user1012750 - You share POCO entities.  That is, you define the entities as Plain old classes, with no attributes or anything other than properties.  You use the same classes for entities in both EF and L2S.  You use POCO's as normal in EF and you use the External Mapping XSL files in L2S to use POCO's for both.  Of course, you're screwed if you need navigational properties, because Navigation works different in L2S vs EF, which would also be a problem in your interface solution, so it's a wash either way.

Answer (score -1):

I've found a workaround. I kind of like it so I want to share it.

I rewritten my EFRepository :

```
public class EFRepository<T, W> : 
IRepository<T> where T : class
    where W : class, T
{
    private EFContext _context;

    public EFRepository(IUnitOfWork uow)
    {
        this._context = (EFContext)uow.Context;
    }

    protected DbSet<W> DbSet
    {
        get
        {                
            return _context.Set<W>();
        }
    }

    public IQueryable<T> All
    {
        get
        {
            return DbSet.AsQueryable<T>();
        }
    }

    public virtual int Count
    {
        get
        {
            return DbSet.Count();
        }
    }

    public bool Contains(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
    {
        return All.Count(predicate) > 0;
    }

    public virtual void Create(T item)
    {
        DbSet.Add(item as W);
    }

    public virtual void Update(T TObject)
    {
        var item = DbSet.Attach(TObject as W);

        _context.SetItemState(TObject, EntityState.Modified);
    }

    public virtual void Delete(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
    {
        var objects = All.Where(predicate);

        foreach (var obj in objects)
        {
            DbSet.Remove(obj as W);
        }
    }

    public virtual void Delete(T TObject)
    {
        DbSet.Remove(TObject as W);
    }
}
```

So now basically all I need to do now is

```
IRepository<IAccount>> accRepository = new EFRepository<IAccount, Account>(uow);
```

I am happy with this solution, but still I'm not sure it is the best one, so any comments will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: How exactly do you intend to do navigational properties?  These work different between L2S and EF.  For instance, EF supports many-to-many while L2S does not.

Comment: Well, databases do not support many-to-many relationship, so I will just pass by the  intermediate table. See here : http://www.iaingalloway.com/many-to-many-relationships-in-linq-to-sql

Comment: If you're going to degrade the performance and functionality of EF to match L2S, why even bother with EF?

Comment: I am working with ef but my host provider has problem with it. So i switch between ef and l2s.

Comment: That's not possible.  EF is an entirely client-side tool, your hosting provider has nothing to do with it.  He can't support or not support EF so long as he supports .NET

Comment: Well, thats what they wrote me. But still, dont u think it's a good idea to decorrelate logic code from db tech? Now if i wish i could implement NHibernate (for example) without changing my code except for the IoC